# Reduce size of integral box

Tags: math-mode, boxes, integral

I am trying to write an integral over quite a few factors. Everything put together will easily exceed one line, maybe even two. If I try to align everything with some align environment (be it align, alignat, split, multiline, anything), I will always be faced with a big gap between my first and second line because the vbox of the integral is much bigger than the box of a standard line. Is there a way to reduce the size of my integral box so that I can have the entire integrand closer together?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
   \notag I(\mu)&=\int_\Omega \text{long equation here}\\
   \notag&\hphantom{=\int_{\Omega}}+\text{even more long equation here}\\
   &\hphantom{=\int_{\Omega}}+\text{even even more long equation here}\,\mathrm{d}\mu
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example (MWE) to demonstrate the issue. But you could play around with `\smash`.

Comment: I hope this is an MWE good enough to explain my problem.

Comment: No, it is not an MWE but just a code fragment. Please ad to it used document class as well packages which are needed for compile it.

Comment: `\smash{\int_\Omega}` will remove the height of the integral box.  However, you then have to be concerned about potential overlap with the 2nd line.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it solved by comment.

Comment: I would assume this covers what is required to run the code, but I don't actually know which exact packages are required for this MWE. If this is still incomplete, I am very much sorry.

Comment: of course you should _always_ know, as you should test the example before posting. Here for example your main issue is the `intlimits` option which you had not mentioned until just now.

Comment: Voting to close a zero-scored question as "solved in comments" is a bad idea. Having an actual answer would safe the question from automatically being roombad  https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/roomba and help future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have a multi-line equation, but a single line equation with a multi-line integrand, so I would use `equation` not `align`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
   I(\mu)=\int_\Omega
   \;\begin{aligned}
  &\text{long equation here} +\\
  &\text{even more long equation here}\\
  &\text{even even more long equation here}
   \end{aligned}
\,\mathrm{d}\mu
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem, that arose from this option, was the fact, that I was actually writing even more lines to that equation (with several more "=" signs), such that the align environment complained about too many alignment tabs. I tried to simplify my question as much as possible and might have simplified it too much then.

Comment: no you can have an `align` with a 100 rows, you would not have that error.  @Sellerie

Comment: Is there a substantial difference between the split envorinment and the aligned environment that could explain, why none of this worked with split while it does work with aligned?

Comment: if in doubt use `aligned`. normally they produce the same but `split` is vastly more complicated and can merge with an outer `align` @Sellerie

Comment: Is the described style a standard way of writing an integral with several lines, in particular writing the measure centered at the very end? Many people keep telling me that it is not obvious what that integral term is supposed to mean, even though it seems pretty obvious to me. I haven't seen it anywhere else though. You listed this option very nonchalantly, so I wonder, whether this is something you have encountered often?

Comment: I would probably use`\left(...\right)` around the aligned, then it is all perfectly normal @Sellerie